# Is it possible to use anything similar to $this to refer to the current object in Powershell?

Tags: oop, variables, powershell, reference

I'm attempting to make a Powershell module to work with an external API. I have a custom object which looks like this:

```
$Subscriber = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    [string] $EmailAddress=$null
    [string] $Name=$null
    [bool]   $Resubscribe=$false
    [bool]   $RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders=$false

    Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function *
}
```

Now, I'd like this object to be able to implement a function which outputs itself in JSON format. I'm aware that the normal way to do this is: `$Subscriber | ConvertTo-Json` but instead, I'd like this object to implement something along these lines:

```
$Subscriber = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    [string] $EmailAddress=$null
    [string] $Name=$null
    [bool]   $Resubscribe=$false
    [bool]   $RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders=$false

    Function ToJson {
        $this | ConvertTo-Json
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function *
}
```

But my problem is that there is no $this variable nor have I been able to find any information about any other way to do it. Am I simply attempting to misuse Powershell to such a degree that this isn't supported at all? Or am I just missing something obvious? I'm open to any critique and advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables you define at module scope (eg. `$EmailAddress`) can be accessed<sup>1</sup> from inside functions defined in the module.

However `ConvertTo-Json` converts a single object from the pipeline.

Therefore you would be better defining a single object, and passing that through:

```
$Subscriber = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
              EmailAddress=$null;
              Name=$null;
              Resubscribe=$false;
              RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders=$false
            }

    Function ToJson {
        $data | ConvertTo-Json
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function *
}
```

But this wouldn't really fix with the `-AsCustomObject`, so that conversion to a single object could be done inside `ToJson`:

```
$Subscriber = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    [string] $EmailAddress=$null
    [string] $Name=$null
    [bool]   $Resubscribe=$false
    [bool]   $RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders=$false

    Function ToJson {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
              EmailAddress=$EmailAddress;
              Name=$Name;
              Resubscribe=$Resubscribe;
              RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders=$RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders
            } | ConvertTo-Json
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function *
}
```

(And, as far as I am aware, there is no single `$this` in this case: there certainly isn't for `.psm1` type modules.)

---

<sup>1</sup> And updated if you use the `script:` scope prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it extensively, give it a try. It evaluates the `$^` automatic variable which contains the first token in the last line received by the session (the variable name).

```
function ToJson { Invoke-Expression "$^" | ConvertTo-Json }
```